# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host / php imap - signature has expired

Tags: php, soap, openssl, imap-open

If anyone is having issues with these errors, theres been compatibility changes to LetsEncrypt. Unless both your polling and answering server are on compattible versions, you can fix your error by ensuring that your openssl version is < than the following

```
    OpenSSL <= 1.0.2
    Windows < XP SP3
    macOS < 10.12.1
    iOS < 10 (iPhone 5 is the lowest model that can get to iOS 10)
    Android < 7.1.1 (but >= 2.3.6 will work if served ISRG Root X1 cross-sign)
    Mozilla Firefox < 50
    Ubuntu < 16.04
    Debian < 8
    Java 8 < 8u141
    Java 7 < 7u151
    NSS < 3.26
    Amazon FireOS (Silk Browser)
```

these are the affected clients that will still trust the exiting certificate chain

also, as reference,

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-thread-for-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/149190/264

Answer (score 0):

as described above, and refer to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-thread-for-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/149190/264

Comment: It's better if answers contain all or important snippets of code needed to solve a problem since links can break in the future, and it's also nicer to see everything on one page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).